# Бывают ли конкурсы на заминусованые вопросы?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, конкурс

Было ли когда-нибудь такое? Никогда честно говоря не видел. Почему-то все конкурсные вопросы автоматически собирают плюсики возле себя. Почему так? Является ли это помощью автору, чтобы помочь ему восстановить потерянную репутацию?

Comment: Технически ничто не запрещает, насколько мне известно. Объявление конкурса привлекает внимание. А привлекать внимание к плохим вопросам занятие довольно бессмысленное. Поэтому то, что конкурсные вопросы собирают плюсики, это скорее следствие рационального поведения тех, кто объявляет конкурсы.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Я видел несколько раз конкурсные вопросы с -1, -2 и ниже. Поэтому короткий ответ: да. И не всегда конкурс объявляют с уверенностью, что это супер-пупер вопрос. Бывает очень посредственные вопросы, но видимо человеку просто очень нужно решение (например, по работе), а у него ничего не выходит. Поэтому правило D-side о том, что "привлекать внимание к плохим вопросам занятие довольно бессмысленное" далеко не всегда работает. Ещё часто бывает вопрос имеет нулевую репутацию по окончанию конкурса, поэтому нельзя сказать, что "**все** конкурсные вопросы автоматически собирают плюсики возле себя". Можете помониторить enSO для подтверждения.

Поэтому очень советую тем, кто рассматривает объявление конкурса не уповать на то, что он 100% принесёт результат, решит проблему и приманит великого мудреца. Особенно на тяжёлый и/или узкоспециализированный вопрос. Далеко не всегда конкурс приманит "кого надо" и **тем более** "окупится". Будьте готовы просто расстаться с репутацией и воспринимайте полезные ответы и плюсы других пользователей как неожиданный подарок.

Comment: @EugenEray Я не имею  кого-то лично ввиду, и не намекаю на способ накрутки. Просто бывает обидно, когда совершенно напрасно пожертвовали серьёзным куском репутации (к примеру 250 или 500), ничего не получив взамен. Не всегда конкурсы помогают. Поэтому просто советую спокойно расставаться с репутацией и давать сколько не жалко.